# segmentation fault at `mov byte [esi+7], al`

Tags: assembly, shellcode

```
Section .text
        global _start

_start:
        jmp short GoToCall

shellcode:
        pop             esi
        xor             eax, eax
        mov byte        [esi+7], al
        lea             ebx, [esi]
        mov long        [esi + 8], ebx
        mov long        [esi + 12], eax
        mov byte        al, 0x0b
        mov             ebx, [esi]
        lea             ecx, [esi + 8]
        lea             edx, [esi + 12]
        int             0x80

GoToCall:
        Call shellcode
        db      "/bin/shJAAAABBBB"
```

After compiling the above shellcode I got below disassembly. where at 3rd line I am getting the Segmentaion fault.

```
(gdb) disassemble shellcode 
Dump of assembler code for function shellcode:
   0x08049002 <+0>: pop    %esi
   0x08049003 <+1>: xor    %eax,%eax
=> 0x08049005 <+3>: mov    %al,0x7(%esi)
   0x08049008 <+6>: lea    (%esi),%ebx
   0x0804900a <+8>: mov    %ebx,0x8(%esi)
   0x0804900d <+11>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esi)
   0x08049010 <+14>:    mov    $0xb,%al
   0x08049012 <+16>:    mov    (%esi),%ebx
   0x08049014 <+18>:    lea    0x8(%esi),%ecx
   0x08049017 <+21>:    lea    0xc(%esi),%edx
   0x0804901a <+24>:    int    $0x80
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) printf "%s", $esi
/bin/shJAAAABBBB(gdb) printf "%s", $esi+7
JAAAABBBB(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08049005 in shellcode ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction that causes the SIGSEGV is trying to store a `'\0'` after the `'h'` in `"/bin/shJAAAABBBB"`.

All your code/data is in the `.text` section which is probably read-only.
Run `objdump -h` on the resulting binary, and you should see something like the following in the output:

```
  5 .text         00000031  00001000  00001000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
```

which contains the addresses where the bytes of the string are stored.

Comment: Actually for ELF executable, memory protections are set according to the segment and not the section. But anyways, you're right.

Comment: If I want to write into the `"/bin/shJAAAABBBB"` and execute the shellcode what update I have to make in the assemble?

Answer (score 1):

The memory where you shellcode is located and executed is not writable.
It could happen for different reasons, my guess is your shellcode is encoded as a C literal string. Since this memory location is not writable, so you get an exception.

If you just want to try the shellcode, allocate a memory page using `mmap(2)` with flag `PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`, copy your shellcode inside and jump on it.

By the way, your shellcode is null byte free, if you copy it using `strcpy(3)` function, you can remove both `xor eax, eax` and `mov [esi+7], al` because `strcpy(3)` will write the 0x00 for you. Just make sure to trim "/bin/shJAAAABBBB" to "/bin/sh".

Answer (score 1):

It's because `/bin/sh` needs `\0`, so replace it `"AAAABBBB"` with `\0`

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of @booto shows, `objdump -h` prints out `.text` section is readonly.

You can try to compile like this and don't have to update the original source code:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o ./Execve.o Execve.nasm
ld -N -o ./Execve ./Execve.o
```

`ld -N`:

> Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable.